# Connecting to a database using Apple's Instruments Automation

Tags: javascript, ios, sql, sql-server-2008, instruments

I am attempting to automate an iPhone native app using Apple's Instruments Automation tool.  The tests are written in Javascript and it works quite well but I really need to be able to connect to a SQL server database so that I can query for specific data to be used in the automation tests.  Is this possible to do?